# Install-SPSolution : This solution contains no resources scoped for a Web application and cannot be deployed to a particular Web application

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have a PowerShell script that deploys about 12 web parts. They have all been created in the manner through visual studio 2010 and are being deployed to SharePoint 2010.

I am getting the following error when running Install-SPSolution for one of my web parts:
Install-SPSolution : This solution contains no resources scoped for a Web application and cannot be deployed to a particular Web application.

Can someone help me debug this? Every other Install-SPSolution command uses -AllWebApplications, and I do not want to specify the web application directly using -URL. Here is the command that is breaking (this is the same command used to successfully deploy all 11 other web parts):

```
Install-SPSolution –Identity PortalSelector.wsp -AllWebApplications -GACDeployment
```

Comment: You might try posting this on http://ServerFault.com - more admins hang out there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wow, this is old.  You're probably a PS guru by now.

For the archives / next visitor give the following a try:

Install-SPSolution –Identity PortalSelector.wsp -GACDeployment

or

Install-SPSolution –Identity PortalSelector.wsp -GACDeployment -Confirm:$false

The latter prevents the confirmation dialog from popping up.

Comment: lol, yup, way beyond that now... but thanks, that is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Event i found the same issue when im started working on sharepoint 2010. This is the solution i found and sharing it may helps to others

http://programming.cmsstores.com/this-solution-contains-no-resources-scoped-for-a-web-application-sharepoint-wsp-exception/

Comment: That link is stale; what was the solution?